# Evil paste behaviour

Tags: evil, copy-paste

I'm noticing odd behaviour when I select some text with control-space and use `p` to paste -- in that the paste is done after the cursor character, rather than on the next line. Is that intentional, configurable, or a bug? This is evil from git.

For example, if my buffer is

```
one
two
three
four
```

When I copy the first two lines (cursor on 'o', `C-space`, `jj`, `M-w`) and paste with the cursor on 'f' of the last line, then the result is

```
one
two
three
fone
two
tour
```

If I use `2yy` to copy the lines then the paste works as expected.

My .emacs contains minimal evil configuration, but removing it makes no difference.

```
(setq evil-cross-lines t
      evil-move-beyond-eol t
      evil-want-fine-undo t
      evil-symbol-word-search t)

(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-w" 'evil-delete)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\C-w" 'evil-delete)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "\C-w" 'evil-delete)
```

Comment: I believe that's intended. That's how paste works with vim.

Comment: If it behaves the same as in Vim, it's not a bug. The whole point of Evil is to be a faithful Vim emulation.

Comment: Hmm, if I do a visual mode select in vim, y and p, then it does indeed behave the same way. I never use visual mode in vi, so never noticed. Viper behaves differently (and makes more sense IMHO), but I get your point in faithful emulation. So what is the best way to copy-paste as I want, if I want to use c-space select? It's very clumsy to have to create a new line first (o, esc), and then paste.